# Design system with historical data integrity while storing realtime events

Tags: java, architecture, storage, real-time

I am creating system, that collects real-time data from various channels using Java server and stores this data in NoSql database. I have N nodes, each node responsible for own set of channels.

One of my requirement is data integrity. Given that, i need to handle next two cases:

1. When PC is shutdowned, or JVM fails -> on next startup system should get offline time and create job for reducing data history gap
2. When NoSql storage is unavailable -> system should persist data somewhere (either realtime data, or gaps time data)

So, my questions are:

- How i can track offline hours for each node?
- Should i use some internal storage (like SqlLite) with heartbeats?
- Should i use original database with heartbeats?
- What is general approach for managing such cases?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In case of JVM fail - where would your system get the data that was not collected in Real-Time?

Comment: @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz have such possibility using regular http api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing you must keep in mind before drafting any architecture is the [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) theorem, saying that you can't have a system with high performance, 
high level of consistency and partitioning - at least one of the parameters should be sacrificed to sustain the other two. It seems to me that you want all of them, which is impossible, so you need to decide what is more important for your business domain.

Since I don't know all the details of your system + I don't even know what is the business domain all I can suggest is a general approach to the requirements that you have got. Taking into account all the above, here is a general approach:

**1. REST API (or API Gateway).** Obviously, it will be serving client requests. The main idea here is that it will return the same response basically for all of the requests telling them that we accepted the request for processing. On this step, we push messages to the message broker.

**2. Message Broker (Kafka, RabbitMQ etc.).** This is where we store our requests for async processing.

**3. Your applications.** They will listen to the queues in the message broker, and whenever the message is there the app just consumes it for a processing. After processing is completed the app will store the result in DB.

**4. DB.** Just stores the result of the processing performed by the app.

The idea is that if your message broker is down - the client will be notified immediately that the message can't be processed. In case the application is down - message won't be lost because they are in the queue. If the DB is down - messages will be in the queue still since the app won't be able to consume it.
Note that your queue won't likely to be down if you do everything properly. Message brokers nowadays are really (like reallllyy) fast and very good at scale, for instance, Kafka handles billions of messages at Linkedin and it all works fine for them.

Hopefully, this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Totally agree with kafka usage, we already decided to use it.